# When i try to invite my bot, The Application Icon is not Showing up Discord

Tags: discord

**Application Icon**
[image: Application Icon]

**Bot Invite**
[image: Bot Invite]

Is there a way to fix this issue, I tried on multiple devices and it still refused to show, The logo was published days ago.

Comment: Did you tried to remove and invite it back?

Comment: @MichaelŠtekrt  yes i did and i tried it on multiple devices and still nothing.

Comment: I know i had same error when i was creating my bot. I solve it by using some setIcon i think..

Comment: The issue is more related to application icon not the bot icon it self
Edit: Both application icon and bot icon are different, The normal bot icon works well but the application one the one you supposed to see when inviting the bot doesn't show